# vs2012 web project import existing files and folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How can i take an existing website (files and folders) that exist on my hard drive into a VS2012 project?

I am trying to highlight the files/ folders in explorer and drag/ drop into the project but that doesn't work in 2012.

I am trying to get the existing site imported into a blank website project and don't want all the extra files VS adds as part of lets say a win forms project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In VS2012 `Solution Explorer`:

Right Click on your Solution Name > `Add` > `Existing Website`

You can select your existing website files here.

Hope it solves your query.